# STM32L432KC DAC wrong pin

Tags: stm32, dac

When I'm trying to output something using DAC the voltage appears on pin A3 not on A4 as expected. Am I missing something?

```
#include "main.h"

DAC_HandleTypeDef hdac1;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DAC1_Init(void);

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t DAC_OUT[4] = {0, 1241, 2482, 3723};
    uint8_t i = 0;
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_DAC1_Init();
    HAL_DAC_Start(&hdac1, DAC1_CHANNEL_1);
    while (1)
    {
        DAC1->DHR12R1 = DAC_OUT[i++];
        if(i == 4)
        {
            i = 0;
        }
        HAL_Delay(50);
    }
}
```

[image: Configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just looked at the pinout - for some reason, PA_4 is connected to A3 not A4 - problem solved I guess. It's weird though because for example PA_1 is connected to A1 etc.